# Small Window Over Components

Tags: java, swing, window, components

I already look at java library and dont know what to use to do this..
I already tryed JInternalFrame but thats not what I really want.. because it needs to be added to a JDesktopPanel right??

And in my program I have a JFrame with content pane using BorderLayout..
Then on borderlayout center I have a JTextArea, on borderlayout east I have a list.. and on borderlayout south I have a JPanel..

What I want is, when I do a certain action, it will pop up a "mini window" where I need to choose something.. u see?
and if I create JDesktopLane it will overlap what I have on the container..

the window will be made by my like a color chooser pallete , like a grid with colors.. and a label on top saying some text..

I just dont know how to make a "window" over the other components, and users can still drag over the frame, and interact with all the other components.. the jtextarea and such..

I guess you understood, thanks alot in advance!! 
If u dont understand something please tell me, I really want to do this :)
Just dont know what to use..

Thanks again ;)

Comment: I forgot to say, I dont want to use another JFrame.. that is kinda bad for code, its a small window with a simple function.. choose a color from a grid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical class for this task is `JWindow`, a borderless top-level window that can be freely positioned. You could use `SwingUtilities.getPointFromComponent` to get the screen coordinates for a realized coordinate.

Top-level windows (JFrame, JDialog, JWindow) are not added to containers. They can get other windows as parent.

> I dont want to use another JFrame.. that is kinda bad for code, its a small window with a simple function..

Structure your code so you can read it, others can read it, and you can debug it easily (the latter is a result from the first). A low class count is useless and -most of the time- contraproductive.

Why should another JFrame (or other window) be bad?

If you absolutely want to avoid opening top level windows (e.g. to avoid applet warning icons or to implement a special kind of user interface) you could use a `JLayeredPane` to add additional `JPanel`s above your existing GUI elements.

Comment: I mean.. if I want to use this on a applet.. 2 frames wont work, my teacher told me :s
the best graphical code is the one that uses only one frame.. and then u add everything u want to it.. 
so u are saying that I can add JWindow to frame contentor ? thanks

Comment: Technically multiple windows are needed quite often (like here, for popups). From an user experience one *main* window may be enough (for end user applications); still there will be dialogs and popups. From class count or developer view it doesn't matter - of course two windows work, what should prevent it? / Applets have a limitation: When you open a window from an Applet you get a small warning icon besides the window so you can't trap the user into pretending to open system windows from web pages.

Comment: Hmm but JPanels cant be dragged right? I need to make a costume class extind JPanel and add mouse listeners for the "drag window" ? thanks in advance

Comment: ok thanks guys ;)
just tell me later if it causes problems on applets, because I will run it on applet later

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html)?

Comment: Yes , but I cant add it to the content pane of the frame.. it gives me error on console.
thanks for ur reply


`the error is : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container`

Comment: You don't add a JDialog to a JFrame. You create the dialog the same way you create a JFrame and just make it visible.

Comment: It worked!! this might be what I am looking for :)
Does it gives problems on applets ? thanks btw

Comment: I have one question! Do I need to dispose JDialog ? when I Click "X" button to close ?   or does it dispose auto?

Comment: Exiting the window should release all its resources.  Call 'dispose' to close it programmatically.

Comment: hm okay thats what I want to know, I dont wanna to have resources still running after closing. but u say that it releases them all, then fine :) thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It's because Jdialog are not component to be add in a JFrame, it's an independant thing running on it's own

if you use JDialog, the construct parameter parent indicate wich frame the JDialog is related to.